# Whether Methods could be defined in Constructors in Java?

Tags: java

I am learning to program in Java and have run into a situation I don't understand.

I have this code

```
import java.io.*; 
class temp 
{ 
  temp() 
  { 
    Finish f=new Finish();
    f.end(); 
  } 

  public static void main(String args[]) 
  {
    System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM"); 
  } 
} 

class Finish 
{ 
  public void end() 
  { 
    System.out.println("ENDING JAVA PROGRAM"); 
  } 
}
```

I expected the code to print

```
STARTING JAVA PROGRAM
ENDING JAVA PROGRAM
```

but I am only getting

```
STARTING JAVA PROGRAM
```

Is it possible to call a method from a constructor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should you use Local Classes in Java?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/240532/when-should-you-use-local-classes-in-java) (methods could be defined in local classes which, in turn, could be defined within constructor)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you would want to achieve with such methods that are defined in a constructor.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:I would like to check whether this code is right or wrong.Code is:import java.io.*;
class temp
{
temp()
{
Finish f=new Finish();f.end();
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM");
}
}
class Finish
{
public void end()
{
System.out.println("ENDING JAVA PROGRAM");
}
}Here I haven't defined any method but I have called a method.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Sorry.I've updated the previous comment.In the comment I didn't write `f.end()`.But now I have written it in the previous comment.

Comment: @justin: Have you tried the code? If you ask why that code doesn't do what you expect (presenting the code, your expectation and the actual result), you have a reasonable question to ask over at [so].

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Yes the code works but it doesn't display"ENDING JAVA PROGRAM".That's why I asked can we place a method call inside a constructor.Could you help me.

Comment: @justin: I have rewritten your question. I have also flagged it for migration to [so], as the question is better suited for there (it it primarily based off the code, rather than conceptual).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau:Thanks for editing.Now the post looks good.

Comment: U need to create an object of *temp* in the main to acheive what you want

Comment: Failure to migrate indicates possibility of a question block at SO.
Do not post off-topic content on a site in an [attempt to circumvent a block on another site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination). This is not an appropriate question here - if you wish to get out of the block on Stack Overflow, please read the linked article that appears on the block message. You know, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an object of *temp* in the main to acheive what you want.

To get the result that you want add the below in your main:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) 
      {
        System.out.println("STARTING JAVA PROGRAM"); 
        temp t = new temp(); //New temp object
      }
```

Comment: :Now it has shown full output.

Comment: or just call the constructor. "new temp();"

Comment: @ne2dmar for sure